# While trying to play movies from servers some URL's doesn't work. Why?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to run a streaming video in `MPMoviePlayerController`. When I was trying some urls like `http://code.agilephil.com/fox.m4v` it was working. But when I try some other urls like one in our remote server, it doesnt work and in Console it says `Playback stopped`.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I figured out was
1.it was working when posted in a IIS server even in the simulator. 
2. When posted in webserver, wasnt working in simulator but successfully worked in device.